# How do I append a Column to a MATLAB Table based on certain conditions?

Tags: database, matlab, loops

I have a MATLAB Table of dimensions 5000x6. I would like to add a new column to the MATLAB Table based on certain conditions for the 6th Column in the original table.

I want the following:-
1. If the 6th Column value is less than x or greater than y: Append a 1 to the new 7th Column of the MATLAB Table
2. Else, append a 0 to the new 7th Column of the MATLAB Table

So, finally, what I will have is a 5000x7 Table, with the last(7th column) consisting of 0s and 1s based on the values in the original (6th) column. I am new to working with Tables and Iterations in MATLAB, and I tried looking at other questions on Stackoverflow but couldn't get any idea of how I can do this stuff. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Consider preallocating the memory for your matrix. If you create a 5000x6 Matrix and expand it to 5000x7 matlab will take the double length of the current matrix in space -> 5000x12. Which for large matrices ends up taking considerable amounts of memory...

Comment: That's definitely the way to do it Pablo. If the answer solved your problem please accept it as correct @Joyjit Chatterjee.

Comment: Thanks @matiastofteby!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I imagine you have extracted your sixth column from your data matrix. I've called it A. Then you define upper and lower bounds for you logical one indexing.

Then you create your new column by checking each element in your vector against your bounds and finally add it to your matrix.

```
% Sixth column
A = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 3; 1; 2; 8];

y= 4; % Upper boundary
x= 2; % Lower boundary

% Create logical column vector by information of sixth column
new_column = (A<x) | (A>y);

% Add new column to Matrix
A = [A new_column];
```

I just created some random bounds and values for your vector.